# Laravel Eloquent query builder combination

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

So I need to find all `ProductionTask` that `belongTo` certain `Operation` if

- where `'status', '<', 3`
- `orWhere('expected_start', '>', $monday_date)`

with implementation of `orWhere` the column `operation_id` from eloquent relationship with `Operation` is being ignored.

What should I do?

Here's the faulty code:

```
   return production\ProductionTask::where('operation_id', $operation->id)->where('status', '<', 3)->orWhere('expected_start', '>', $monday_date)->and('expected_end', '<', $sunday_date)->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

```
return production\ProductionTask::where('operation_id', $operation->id)
     ->where(function($q) use($monday_date) {
         $q->where('status', '<', 3)->orWhere('expected_start', '>', $monday_date);
     }->where('expected_end', '<', $sunday_date)->get();
```

to group your `where` conditions.

Using this you will get:

```
SELECT * FROM production_tasks WHERE operation_id = ? AND (status < 3 OR expected_start > ?) AND expected_end < ?
```

Using previous way you were getting something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM production_tasks WHERE operation_id = ? AND status < 3 OR expected_start > ? AND expected_end < ?
```

and it equals to:

```
SELECT * FROM production_tasks WHERE (operation_id = ? AND status < 3) OR (expected_start > ? AND expected_end < ?)
```